# Upgrading to WebMatrix SimpleMembership

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I installed MVC 4 when it was in beta, so I didn't get the SimpleMembership library back then. Now I've built a large project using the old MembershipProvider and was wondering how to upgrade from that to `WebMatrix SimpleMembership`.

I've already created the database schema and EF model and mapping classes. Now I'm wondering how I can upgrade the rest (install required libraries, etc.)

Is there some `upgrade path` I can follow, just to bypass screwing up my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the upgrade path I used:

1. Backup everything (Code and SQL)
2. Create a new Internet Application `[with SimpleMembership]`
3. Move following folders from old project to new project:

   - Scripts
   - Content
   - Images
   - Controllers `[don't overwrite AccountController]`
   - Models `[don't overwrite AccountModels]`
   - Views
4. Insert connectionString from old project into Web.config
5. Run project and create a new user. Then the SimpleMembership SQL tables will be created automatically.
6. Use [Entity Framework Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d), right click on project and choose `Entity Framework -> Reverse Engineer Code First`, to generate all EF entity/mapping classes for all SQL tables.
7. Delete `UserProfile` entity and `UserProfileMap` classes, because they come with SimpleMembership's `AccountModels`.
8. Refactor GUID to integer in all project.